# Remove drag table in field collection module drupal 7

Tags: nodes, entities

Hihi. Hi all. I have a content type and in which I created a collection field using [field collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module. I set the value for the field collection that is unlimited. In field collection including some certain fields. Then I proceeded to create content for this content type. I discovered that the field collection module enables drag row and show weight of the current row. Now I want to remove drag and drop function and the weight of that row without knowing how processing. Expect people to help me handle this problem. Thank all.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To removing ajax dag and drop table widget for multiple value field you need use "hook_theme_registry_alter" to override theme registry function. [Here](https://www.commercialprogression.com/post/how-remove-tabledrag-rearranging-multiple-value-field-widgets) you can find all information regarding your question.